# Is there a way to animate a material differently for object that has it? I want these blossoms to turn pink one after another

Tags: animation

[image]

Can i get the second blossom's colour to change ***after***  the first one's without having to create a new material?

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to stagger when the blossoms start changing colors, you can use a node set up like this one:
[image: Node tree]
The value node is keyframed to 0 at frame 1 and 2 at the frame when you want them to have finished changing colors.
[This is what that would look like over 60 frames @ 15fps.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/czntM.jpg)

The random input generates a number between 0 and 1. That is our offset for when the object's color starts changing. The color ramp takes an input between 0 and 1 (if the input is greater than 1, then it is treated as 1) and outputs a color based on that. If you didn't stagger the color changes, then you could just animate the color ramp input from 0 to 1. The subtract node is used so that the random number from the object info node delays when the animated value (which is animated from 0 to 2, so that even if the random value is 1, at the end of the animation, its input to the color ramp is 1) reaches 1, which is the final color on the color ramp.

Also, I would recommend going into the dope sheet, selecting the key frames for the material, and setting the interpolation to linear.

That said, I'm not sure how to ensure that the blossoms change colors only one at a time without using multiple materials.

Comment: Can you expand on what the nodes are doing? Why the subtraction operation?

Comment: @no-can-do I have included more information in the answer. Let me know if that answers your question!

Comment: Thanks, keep in mind that things are not obvious for new users. If you explain the logic instead of just the result, we all learn.